# Typescript array push method can't catch a tuple type of the array

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const testArray:[number, string] = [10, 'test', 's'];
```

It doesn't work.

```
const testArray:[number, string] = [10, 'test']; // It's been edited.
testArray.push('test');
```

It works.

I think second code shouldn't worked.
Why does the second code work? Is it a bug?

---

-Added-

I've been thinking about the problem.
Compiler can catch errors only in compile time. So the compiler doesn't catch the error. Is it right?

Comment: How would you expect `let testArray:[number, string];` behave?  It's undefined upon declaration.

Comment: @Taplar  I understand why the first code doesn't work. so I thought the second one also doesn't work. that's why I posted this question.

Answer (score 31):

This is a good question, and I'll try to rephrase it as explicitly as possible:

> [Tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) are a type of array of known length and where the different elements may have different types.  A value of type `[number, string]` is guaranteed to have a `length` of `2`, with a `number` at element `0` and a `string` at element `1`.
>
> Why then, does TypeScript allow you to call methods like `push()`, `pop()`, `shift()`, `unshift()`, and `splice()` on values of tuple types, when such methods generally destroy the supposed guarantees of tuple types?  Shouldn't it *stop* you from doing that, just like it stops you from assigning a value like `[1, "two", "three"]` to `[number, string]` in the first place?

Yeah, it's not great.

I don't know that there's a good canonical answer to this.  The closest I can find is [microsoft/TypeScript#6325](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6325), which proposes that such methods be omitted from tuple types.  This proposal was declined, on the possible grounds that it would be [a breaking change](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6325#issuecomment-168588269) for existing real-world code.

A suggested alternative looks like

```
type StrictTuple<T extends any[]> =
    Omit<T, keyof (any[])> extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
```

which looks less like an array and more like a set of numeric-key properties:

```
const x: StrictTuple<[number, string]> = [1, ""] // {0: number; 1: string }
x[1] = "okay";
x[0] = 123;
x.push(123); // error!
//~~~~ Property 'push' does not exist on type { 0: number; 1: string; }
```

If you really care about such things, you might want to use something like `StrictTuple` above, but it's probably more trouble than it's worth.  Tuple types are ubiquitous in TypeScript and if you use a form that is not assignable to them, then you will have to jump through a lot of unfortunate hoops to use TypeScript.

Pragmatically speaking, I'd say just try not to mutate tuples.

There have been some newer issues referencing microsoft/TypeScript#6325 asking to reconsider this now that tuples have gotten a little more strict in the intervening time.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#40316](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40316) and [microsoft/TypeScript#48465](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48465), which are open but not obviously popular. It would be an interesting exercise to see what specifically would break if `push`/`pop`/etc were omitted from tuple types.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAZTAJwJYGMwBUCuUA2MAPFnDAB5gwB2AJgM5wCG1EA2gLoB8cAvHKDhC4AeQC2qMCQA0cANYwIAewBmcABQt2HAJQ8KVOo1TUVMZKLgB+OAG84bANJwT8xatEcAXKKcc4AL5wPtQwAG7mANygoOhK1PRgcOQ+SGiYuATEbNQ4YgBG5rKJaNQA5tx8DgCMsgBEdRyg5GzV-vx1SnJMEHXRIC0ADO1w1QBMAMz9zQB0UDj0ABbq4xM6kXAA9JtwAArISrDIkHAA5PNLp3C0SjCM1EpJFKiJcPFwkLBn9oMheYXIDbVHwlExlDYBGIgIA)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helps a lot.

Comment: @seongkukhan This is the real answer to the question. You should mark it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 9):

[Removed previous answer since I misinterpreted.]

Looks like this could be an issue related to type widening?
You can declare your tuple to be `readonly` or `as const` to prevent the push function from working on the tuple at all

```
const testArray:readonly [number, string] = [10, 'test'] as const;
testArray.push('test') // error
```

I found this medium article on the topic: https://blog.logrocket.com/const-assertions-are-the-killer-new-typescript-feature-b73451f35802/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. but that's not answer I want. I'm sorry. I think I wrote the question complicatedly.

Comment: I updated the answer to hopefully reflect your actual question :)

Comment: `readonly` actually does prevent the mutation. That's a cute trick!

Comment: `readonly` prevents setting the numeric indices too; `testArray[1] = "str";` would be an error; not sure if that's what is actually desired here.

Answer (score 2):

Your types don't match what you're trying to feed it.

```
// Error: Only two elements can be in the tuple
// First index must be a number
// Second index must be a string
const testArray:[number, string] = [10, 'test', 's'];

// Should be this instead
const testArray:[number, string, string] = [10, 'test', 's'];

// Error: Can't initialize value with an empty array
// Needs to provide [number, string] or nothing
const testArray:[number, string] = [];
// Error: You're trying to push a string
// when it's expecting [number, string]
testArray.push('test');

// Should be this
const testArray:[number, string] = [0, 'test'];
testArray.push(1, 'test');
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple

Comment: I understand why the first code doesn't work because It doesn't match to the type. but I thought second one also doesn't work because If I push 'test' to the empty array. It won't be matched of the tuple type. but It works. I think It's not the problem in compilation time. that's why the second code works. Is it right?

Comment: well I dont think testArray.push(1, 'test'); should be ok because when you do it
you try to  say that this array should only contain 2 indexes one of string and one of number

Comment: If you do `testArray.push('test')`, you are trying to feed a string value to a tuple type of `number, string`. You can't do that. ...well at tarnspile time at least. TS doesn't matter at runtime.

Comment: ```
const a:[number, string] = [10, 'st'];

a.push('s');
console.log(a);
```
I coded above code and then ran. It's worked without no errors. I tested this code on an online compiler. 'https://www.typescriptlang.org/'.

Comment: That may be true, but it invalidates the object itself since you're saying everything is `[number, string]` but you just pushed a string. So now the format is off. Also, an error such as this would not be caught at runtime, only when the TS compiler runs. Runtime has no clue what TS is.

Comment: ...Not knowing what the use case here makes it difficult, but I would be this is something that could be designed a little better.

Comment: @mwilson That could be. yes. I agree with that. Thank you for your comments. I've got solved my curiosity here. Have a good day :))

Comment: @mwilson: You did not answer the question. He is obviously asking why you can push a third value onto a typed tuple, that is supposed to have only two values and TS does NOT complain at compile time about that. Again, he asks why you can't initially assign 3 values on a tuple that is typed to have two values, but you still can push a third value into it. Just try it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the tuple this way it will throw an error

```
const testArray: Array<[number, string]> = [10, 'test'];   // Correct
const testArray: Array<[number, string]> = [10, 'test', 's']; //Error

const testArray: Array<[number, string]> = [10, 'test']; /Error
const testArray: Array<[number, string]> = [[10,'test']]; //Correct

testArray.push('test'); //Error
testArray.push([11,'test']) //Correct
```

Comment: Lines 1 and 3 are the same in your answer, but you're saying that 1 is correct while 3 throws an error?